# CiviCRM 5.2.2 System Status gives Incorrect Resource URL (Drupal 7.5)

Tags: drupal, error

CiviCRM 5.2.2 (drupal 7.59, ubuntu 16.04.01, mysql 5.7.22, php 7.0.30)
  CiviCRM System Status gives:
Incorrect Resource URL
The Resource URL is not set correctly. Please set the CiviCRM Resource URL.
Cause: In sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Check/Component/Env.php
$arrowUrl = CRM_Core_Config::singleton()->userFrameworkResourceURL . 'packages/jquery/css/images/arrow.png';
$headers = get_headers($arrowUrl);
is returning an empty array.
sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/css/images/arrow.png exists
Site seems to be working Ok otherwise.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs` and check that the first one 'CiviCRM Resource URL' is set - usually `[civicrm.root]/`

It's worth checking `Administer > System Settings > Directories` at the same time.

Comment: `Administer > System Settings > Resource` is `[civicrm.root]/`  
`Administer > System Settings > Directories` all look good.
Btw. `$arrowUrl` resolves to `[civicrm.root]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/css/images/arrow.png`

Comment: `[civicrm.root]` typically resolves to `http://exampe.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/`, so you should be seeing `[civicrm.root]/packages/jquery/css/images/arrow.png`